# Better than depth-first search solution to LeetCode's 'climbing stairs' pr*blem

Tags: python, algorithm, depth-first-search, asymptotic-complexity

I'm doing a problem on LeetCode, [Climbing Stairs](https://leetcode.com/problems/climbing-stairs/description/), which reads as follows:

[image]

I came up with the following solution based on depth-first search:

```
class Solution:
    def climbStairs(self, n):
        """
        :type n: int
        :rtype: int
        """
        stack = [Node()]
        ways = 0
        while stack:
            node = stack.pop()
            if node.reached_top(n):
                ways += 1
            stack.extend(node.get_neighbors(n))
        return ways


class Node(tuple):
    def get_neighbors(self, n):
        return [Node(list(self) + [steps]) for steps in (1, 2) if sum(self) + steps <= n]

    def reached_top(self, n):
        return sum(self) == n
```

So, for example, `Solution().climbStairs(2) == 2` and `Solution().climbStairs(3) == 3` as required. The problem is that this solution exceeds the time limit for an input of `35`:

[image]

Depth-first search seems like a fairly efficient algorithm to solve this problem, but apparently, it isn't; any ideas on how to improve my solution?

Comment: It doesn't matter how efficiently you generate possibilities; generating every possibility one by one is almost never the most efficient way to count things.

Comment: What's wrong with the related article with multiple solutions on leetcode? https://leetcode.com/articles/climbing-stairs/

Comment: I'm trying not to go to the solution straight away, but to first understand what's wrong with this approach. I think I see the way forward, though: to solve the problem using dynamic programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to calculate each answer based on the fact that `solution(n) = solution(n-1) + solution(n-2)`.  Start with the fact that `solution(1) = 1` and `solution(2) = 2` and you can easily calculate out `solution(3)`, `solution(4)`, etc.  Calculate that array out as far as you want.

This code will be fast enough.

The directions to Google after implementing that are "dynamic programming" and "Fibonacci sequence".  Of the two, dynamic programming is the more important thing to learn.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on [btilly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/585411/btilly)'s answer, suppose the number of ways to reach `n` steps is `solution(n)`. At the first step, you can either take a step of length `1` and have `solution(n-1)` ways remaining, or take a step of length `2` and have `solution(n-2)` ways remaining. Since both are mutually exclusive, the total number of ways remaining is `solution(n-1) + solution(n-2)`.

Instead of the 'bottom-up' dynamic programming approach he described, I decided to use a simple recursive function and use memoization using the `memoize` class from https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Memoize. Here is my solution:

```
import collections
import functools


class memoized(object):
    '''Decorator. Caches a function's return value each time it is called.
    If called later with the same arguments, the cached value is returned
    (not reevaluated).
    '''
    def __init__(self, func):
       self.func = func
       self.cache = {}
    def __call__(self, *args):
       if not isinstance(args, collections.Hashable):
          # uncacheable. a list, for instance.
          # better to not cache than blow up.
          return self.func(*args)
       if args in self.cache:
          return self.cache[args]
       else:
          value = self.func(*args)
          self.cache[args] = value
          return value
    def __repr__(self):
       '''Return the function's docstring.'''
       return self.func.__doc__
    def __get__(self, obj, objtype):
       '''Support instance methods.'''
       return functools.partial(self.__call__, obj)


class Solution(object):
    @memoized
    def climbStairs(self, n):
        """
        :type n: int
        :rtype: int
        """
        if n == 1:
            return 1
        elif n == 2:
            return 2
        else:
            return self.climbStairs(n-1) + self.climbStairs(n-2)
```

This solution is accepted by LeetCode:

[image]

Comment: You also could use `functools.lru_cache` as the decorator, `@lru_cache()` instead of `@memoized`. I just tried submitting your solution like that and beat 100% of the python 3 solutions. https://imgur.com/a/8PMer

Answer (score 0):

Here in the above solution, you are counting each and every possibility by generating them. If you calculate `climbStairs(35)` then it should be equals to `14930352`. So here let us assume your function is `f(n)` which calculates the possible ways to climb up to the stair-N. 
Explanation: what is happening here in your solution:

```
// assuming f(x) = 0 where x <= 0 
// and f(1) = 1 && f(2) = 2;
f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-2); 
f(n-1) = f(n-2) + f(n-3);
f(n-2) = f(n-3) + f(n-4);
.
.
.
f(2) = 2;
f(1) = 1;
```

So here you can see that you are calculating the same part again and again, like `f(n-1)` and `f(n-2)`.

You can avoid those re-calculations by saving the possible combinations to reach a particular stair-X. Here is my solution in Java. Used the "dynamic-programming" approach. To calculate `climbStairs(35)` it does it in total **35** steps (instead of that big number of 8 digits).

```
public int climbStairs(int n) {
    int dp[] = new int[n+1];
    if(n==1) {
        return 1;
    } else if(n==2){
        return 2;            
    } else {
        dp[1] = 1;
        dp[2] = 2;

        for(int i =3; i<=n;i++) {
            dp[i] = dp[i-1] + dp[i-2];
        }
        return dp[n];
    }
}
```